# ruby irb up arrow isn't working - gives strange characters such as ^[[A

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, readline, irb

I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.
When I use IRB and use arrow keys I get characters such as:

```
^[[A^[[B^[[C^[[B
```

How to fix?

I posted here instead of Ubuntu as issue is ruby and maybe not just Ubuntu flavor of Linux

Answer (score 2):

This is a common issue on various linux distributions and versions.

You need to have readline

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential (so you have a C compiler for Ruby)
sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev libreadline-dev zlib1g-dev
# The above steps should make sure irb up-arrow works correctly (libreadline-dev)
# Based on using rbenv for managing ruby versions...
rbenv install 2.5.1 # or latest ruby version as desired
rbenv global 2.5.1 # if you want that as default for other sessions
```